Is It Possible to Retrieve the Bribe Paid for Including a Specific Bundle in Ethereum?
I’m currently working on my Bachelor’s thesis about frontrunning and sandwich attacks. As part of my research, I’m exploring how Flashbots enables private transaction bundles through their relay system.
One aspect I’m particularly curious about is whether it’s possible to determine the bribe (or tip) that was paid by a searcher to a block builder in order to include a specific bundle in a block. This is interesting to me because the bribe significantly impacts the searcher’s actual net profit from MEV activities like sandwich attacks.
I’ve looked into transaction receipts and logs but couldn’t find a clear way to directly observe or calculate the bribe amount. Is this information retrievable, or is it inherently private due to the nature of how Flashbots and other private relays operate?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Do you have any specific transaction hash you looked at?
Flash loans utilize a private mempool, and the bribe is paid to the builder upon inclusion, making it difficult to determine the exact amount paid for inclusion.
However, what we can do is attempt to identify the arbitrage opportunity and calculate the profit the wallet retains after repaying all parties involved, assuming flash loans were used.

I think Searchers pay tip(bribe) in two methods:

With gas tip
With coinbase transfer (Flashbot coinbase document)

You can use some visualiser for block builder competition like payload.
Also you can use from eigenphi for tracking searcher.
